# Flink pros and cons of using gradle instead of maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, apache-flink

I am working on a project where I have made a flink data streaming program and given the first run of the code over to another team so they can look at it. They are all big gradle users and asked me if there are any downsides or benefits of switching to using gradle instead of maven for future flink projects.

Now I know there are tons of articles comparing maven and gradle, but I mean specifically regarding apache flink. There are two git hub repos I found that at a glance look like they implement gradle on a flink project, but that is all.

And if you could say what your experience with flink is, that would be beneficial as well.

So what I want to know is this:

**1.) Is there anything like "if a flink project tried to switch to gradle, x, y, and z simply won't work"?**

**2.) Would switching a flink project to gradle be any more cumbersome than switching any other java (should mention this is in java) project between maven and gradle?**

**3.) Does gradle's repo have all the same flink dependencies available as maven's repo does?**

**4.) What is your recommendation for making the switch or not making the switch?**

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fundamental reason which should keep you from using Gradle to build a Flink project. As long as you allow Gradle to pull its dependencies from Maven Central, then it should be able to resolve all Flink dependencies.

You can take a look at `flink/flink-quickstart/flink-quickstart-java/src/main/resources/pom.xml` to see which dependencies are not necessary to be included in the final uber jar. But it usually does not hurt